# COM C++ VARIANT containing multiple arrays

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to make C++ `VARIANT` containing an array for example

Value[2] (Value is `VARIANT` Type) where again Value[0] is array and Value[1] is another array.

Answer (score 0):

Creating array "a" containing 3 elements, where the first element is an integer, the second and the third elements are again arrays of 10 variants:

```
VARIANT e0;
V_VT(&e0) = VT_I4;
V_I4(&e0) = 42;

VARIANT e1;
V_VT(&e1) = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
V_ARRAY(&e1) = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 10);

VARIANT e2;
V_VT(&e2) = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
V_ARRAY(&e2) = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 10);

VARIANT a;
V_VT(&a) = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
V_ARRAY(&a) = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 3);

long index;

index = 0;
SafeArrayPutElement(V_ARRAY(&a), &index, &e0);

index = 1;
SafeArrayPutElement(V_ARRAY(&a), &index, &e1);

index = 2;
SafeArrayPutElement(V_ARRAY(&a), &index, &e2);
```